# How can I format this list into one string?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list that contains a word. Each letter is separated by a space (as seen below).

```
word = ["h", " ", "e", " ", "l", " ", "l", " ", "o", " "]
```

I am trying to get it to print in the format:

```
h e l l o
```

I tried using a print statement (among other things) but it just came out:

```
["h", " ", "e", " ", "l", " ", "l", " ", "o", " "]
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [`str.join(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to join them together as one string:

```
"".join(word)
```

This will join all elements of the array with empty strings, essentially concatenating the strings together into one. Then you can print it:

```
print("".join(word))
```

This will produce

```
h e l l o
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the join function to convert the List into a string:

```
print ("".join(my_word))
```

The "" before .join means that between the characters an empty space will be added. If you want you can put whatever you like, even spaces or digits or strings.

Comment: A minor note, but the OP tagged their question with [tag:python-3.x], meaning your code won't work.